# Install the same version of Ruby in 2 different folders with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rbenv

I installed rbenv from one directory, now I am in another directory and I no longer have the same version of Ruby installed, which I understand is the point of rbenv to have the option of multiple versions of Ruby installed.

I installed rbenv to begin:

```
brew install rbenv
```

Now in the following folder `~/Users/steven/xyz/work/` I installed Ruby 2.3.1:

```
rbenv install 2.3.1
```

Then I was told to add it to my bash_profile using `nano ~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Now when I use `ruby -v` in `~/Users/steven/xyz/work/` I get `ruby 2.3.1p112` which is good.

However, when I jump over to `~/Users/steven/xyz/projects`, `ruby -v` gives me `ruby 2.0.0p648` which is not good.

So, how do I now get Ruby 2.3.1 in the other folder?

Comment: might help to set the global ruby version `rbenv global 2.3.1` which can be overrided using `rbenv local <version>`

Comment: okay I ran `rbenv global 2.3.1` that seemed to work nicely. thanks

Comment: What instructions did you use to install rbenv then Ruby? The [rbenv home page](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) is the best source for information on installation of rbenv and of Rubies using `rbenv install`. At that point, all rbenv managed Rubies are installed in ~/.rbenv, not in the current folder. That's the point of a tool like rbenv, the Rubies are reusable and easily swapped.

Comment: I had no problem installing rbenv with `brew install` on mac osx. Then as I mentioned `rbenv install 2.3.1` to install ruby. It is possible I do not understant the updates made to my `bash_profile` as this was referred to me by a more experienced rails developer. To be honest the rbenv github readme has a lot of information which is great for background knowledge and gaining a better understanding of how rbenv works, but it can be a bit difficult for newcomers trying to get started with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use rbenv you can create a ".ruby-version" file using:

```
rbenv local 2.0.0-p353
```

which is stored inside the .ruby-version file. Just replace `2.0.0-p353`  with your version of Ruby.

You can specify a Ruby version inside gem file if you use RVM:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "2.3.1"
```

When you switch folders it will load the Ruby specified in the Gemfile. For other engines you can use:

```
ruby "2.2.2", :engine => "jruby", :engine_version => "9.0.0.0"
```

Comment: This isn't a RVM question, it's about rbenv, so the RVM related information doesn't really help.

Comment: But I also posted a solution for rbenv?